# How to set Embedded Data in qualtrics with Javascript

Tags: variables, qualtrics

I can't seem to find the answer on how to set embedded data with javascript in Qualtrics.

Here is what I have:

```
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
     Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'TimeStamp', "${date://CurrentTime/MS}" );

});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add it to your survey flow.[image]

Your syntax appears to be correct, so if you do this, you should be good to go!

Comment: A caveat should be mentioned. You cannot set the value of an Embedded Data and call it using piped text within the same question. Maybe there was something I missed but I could not make it work.